# Getting xmlbeans class not found exception even after adding xmlbeans- version.jar

Tags: java, excel, cmd, jar, apache-poi

I tried executing the code to read .xlsx file in java on command line prompt. And i added the following jars in class path:
Poi-2.1.4, poi-ooxml, poi-ooxml-schemas,xmlbeans, commons-collections, curvesapi, stax-api, dom4j.jars

Still I am getting error as mentioned below:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError: org/Apache/xmlbeans/XmlException at ExcelRead.main(ExcelRead.java:24)

Caused by : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeams.XmlExcel
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6kpo.jpg)

Comment: please share your code

Comment: but It seems strange your xmlbeams are sure is not xmlbeans with N?

Comment: I suggest that your read the following article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
It explains what to add to your question to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Sure I'll read that article. Let me share code for now

Comment: the code should be text and not a screenshot, the exception says that your problem is on line ExcelRead:24

Answer (score 0):

as your exception states you are trying to find org.apache.xmlbeams.XmlExceptiom.
but looking a the docs I found https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException.html and the correct package and class name seems to be:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
```